# Coding of cross-over study's effects in a meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, crossover-study

One of the studies to be included in my meta-analysis has a cross-over design: between T1 and T2, a first group does the treatment condition while a second group does the control condition; and vice-versa from T2 to T3, when each group does the other condition. In each time-period, comparisons are made in that study within-group (pre vs post) and between-group.

For the meta-analysis, I am not sure how to code this study's findings other than as two different effects, corresponding to periods T1-T2 and T2-T3. However, this also seems to me like making an error of case independence, since it would be like considering the two effects as coming from independent experiments, whereas the two groups in one "experiment" represent the same subjects (only differently allocated to groups) as in the other "experiment".

How is the correct way to code this paper's effects for the meta-analysis?

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to treat it as a parallel group study by ignoring T3.

Comment: You don't mean ignoring the entire T2-to-T3 period, i.e. only including the first phase? What about the data from the second phase of the cross-over?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I mean.

Comment: But surely this means ditching half of the study's data?! Why would one not also take the second phase into account, where groups exchange conditions? Is it because of the unwanted dependency reason I mentioned, or some other reason?

Comment: The problem comes with carry-over and period effects. Try https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_4_cross_over_trials.htm for some explanation of possible approaches.